# How to draw triangles on sub-pixels in OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, antialiasing

I'm trying to animate slow movement of two triangles in OpenGL ES.

Although my phase offset is a float which is incremented by 0.003f in every iteration of the run loop, my triangles don't move for a while and then just jump by one pixel to the right.

```
GLfloat vertices[ ] = {
        rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y
    };

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

I confirmed that the values are floats with fractional digits. For example:
0, 0.003, 0.006, ... 0.3, 0.303, 0.306, ... and so on.

So instead of slowly interpolating between pixels OpenGL ES just jumps down. When I set vertices to values like 0.5 then I get them positioned between two pixels. But setting to 0.6 has no effect, 0.7 either, and then it just snaps to the next pixel. As if it was rounding those values to either full or dividable by 0.5. I want a smooth interpolation between pixels so the animation looks nice when it moves very slow.

What must I do so it interpolates vertices between sub-pixels instead of just snapping to a pixel?

Comment: Do you have some sort of way of doing anti-aliasing?

Comment: Do you see this same behavior when using the built-in multisample antialiasing support: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW12 ?

Comment: @Brad Larson Even with multisampling I cannot position vertices between sub pixels.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using `highp` precision for your coordinates in your vertex shader? This should be the default, unless you explicitly override with `mediump` or `lowp` precisions.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL ES 1.0, so no vertex shader. Didn't set anything regarding precision.

Comment: OK, but you had the question tagged as being for OpenGL ES 2.0. If we're talking about 1.1 here, I'll go ahead and remove the 2.0 tag.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Thought maybe the problem overlaps with OpenGL ES 2.0. So there's no way to set that in 1.0?

Comment: 2.0 and 1.1 should treat rendering to the screen in about the same way. Why I asked about precision is that in 2.0, you could override the default `highp` precision with something like `lowp` and significantly reduce your dynamic range (down to only 256 horizontal or vertical steps with `lowp`, for example).